# How, during a segue, can an UIView remain on top of the segue animation?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a storyboard segue, and while showing the new view, I want an UIView to always stay on top, so the segue does not affect it. Tried animating `insertSubview`, but it does not have the push from bottom animation.

Comment: I can only think of one way - fake it (or something very similar to that). Since you are talking about a segue between two view controllers, those views (and their controllers) *cannot* be the parent of this "always stay on top" view, right? So you are left with having the opposite - have those two views (and their controllers) be *children* of the "always stay on top" view and it's controller. And yeah, at that point, why use a segue? Write your own animation - thus my comment about faking it.

Comment: Can you show me how, please?

Comment: Two comments coming up. First, I use storyboards (or IB) only as a straightforward navigation pipeline with segues. I like to code my views and view controllers. There's little you can do in code that cannot be done in IB, so this might be able to be done there. But in that regard, I cannot be of much help. So let's speak strictly in terms of MVC, focusing on the VC (both views and controllers) portion of it. Views can have subviews and view controllers can have child view controllers, right? Here's the important point - a subview or child view controller can have *only* one parent....

Comment: So laying out the view hierarchy, no matter *how* you animate from one view/screen to another, I can only think of one way to have a view on top (#top) of this animation - if those views (#before and #after) are somehow children of the #top. Now each *may* have their own controller, but that really depends on what each view needs to do. The simplest setup is to have only one controller, so let's start with that. If you have a two level hierarchy (#top with child #before and #after) you can remove the segue - after all it's only an animation. In fact, before storyboards that *was* what you did.

Comment: I understand, but I do not know how to make the animation, haven't worked with custom ones :(

Comment: The problem is that I use storyboards, so I can't make a subview of the view a parent to the view.

Comment: I've never done custom animations in IB, but only in code. Basically for a "swipe left" you can, using either auto layout or frames, send one view off to the left and bring a second one on by changing a leadingAnchor (auto layout) or origin X (frames) and then animating. As for view hierarchy in IB, I think you need to add an empty view to the main view, then add views to it. Both of these are really questions unto itself. If nobody has a better alternative, ask new questions about those.

Comment: I want a swipe up animation, is this similar?

Comment: Sure, except you'd give #before a topAnchor/originY of something negative (probably the screen bounds) with #after either having it's topAchor bound to #before's bottomAnchor or setting it's originY to 0 (zero).

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! I hope I will do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code I quickly whipped up showing two view controllers, the one you are going to and one from. I put the animation in a function called `buttonPressed`, but it should go whatever function that calls the transition. Rest of the code is pretty self explanatory.

For this to work both view controllers will need a view with same name (or different names but keep track of which is which), I use `IBOutlet staticView`. And then in interface builder make sure they have the same constraints or frame so that when you set on vc's static view to another it sticks to same spot.

```
class ViewControllerFrom: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var staticView: UIView!

        @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

            let toVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "toVC") as! ViewControllerTo

            //Add nextVC's view to ours as subview
            self.view.addSubview(toVC.view)

            //Set its starting height to be below current view.
            toVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)

            //This is important to make sure staticView stays in front of view animating in
            view.bringSubview(toFront: staticView)
            if toVC.staticView != nil {
                toVC.staticView.isHidden = true
            }
            //I use animation duration 0.4, close to default animations by iOS.
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                toVC.view.frame.origin.y = 0
            }, completion: { (success) in
                if success {
                    //Now that view is in place, set static view from old vc to new vc and reshow it. Then do the actual presentation unanimated.
                    toVC.staticView.isHidden = false
                    toVC.staticView = self.staticView
                    self.present(toVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
                }
            })
        }

    }

    class ViewControllerTo : UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var staticView: UIView!

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually, I improved your code a bit, so that `staticView` is only present on the first view: making an exact copy of it and using `insertSubview` with an index of, let's say, 3, then inserting the `toVc.view` at the index of 2. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah you definitely don't need a variable for `staticView`, but just in case you were perhaps going to reference later within your implementation of your "toVC" its nice to pass the same instance from one VC to the next.